# Are articles pronouns?

Tags: pronouns, articles, parts-of-speech, syntactic-analysis, negative-polarity-items

I'd like to know whether articles are a kind of pronoun. I believe that "a/an" should be an indefinite pronoun because "a" is similar to "any", and "the" should be a definite pronoun. For example:

- I need an answer
- I need any answer

The two words above are similar, but have some differences. In the comments and answers here, it seems that some grammars regard *any* as a determiner when followed by a noun, but as a pronoun when appearing on its own.

On the other hand some grammars and dictionaries regard *any* as a determiner all the time. But determiner is not a standard part of English grammar, and thus is not in the same category as pronoun.

So I believe that there are strong reasons to regard *a/an* as an indefinite pronoun and *the* as a definite pronoun. There is no need for article to be listed as a separate category. The bottom line is that *a* and *any* do not have to be exactly the same for them to be in the same category.

### Update:

Now I believe that articles are listed as a separate category simply because they are the most frequently used pronouns. It is well known that most countable nouns need articles ahead of them.

Comment: Can you give an example of a sentence where "a" is used as a pronoun?

Comment: Lots of examples, "I need an answer" and "I need any answer" as well as "I need some answers" are similar.  So "a" is same as "any" or "some".

Comment: But it's not a pronoun.  "I'm out of left-handed smoke shifters.  Do you have a?"  Doesn't work.

Comment: "Any" is a determinative, not a pronoun. Both "a" and "any" function as determiners.

Comment: Please DON'T close this question! It's anti-intuitively a very good question.

Comment: "A" comes from "an", which comes from "one". "I need an answer", literally, means "I need one answer". There was a gradual change in pronunciation, but that is what we're actually saying to this day. A pronoun would *replace* the word "answer". As in, "I need it". You can't replace the word "answer" with an "a". "I need a" is not a complete sentence syntactically, and makes no sense semantically. I think that before asking such a question, it wouldn't hurt if you at least looked up the definition of a pronoun. "He" is a pronoun. "I" is a pronoun. "We" is a pronoun. "Any" is not a pronoun.

Comment: Quantifiers, such as 'some' or 'one' have been called pronouns if there is no noun in the phrase, but it is better to think of the noun as elided, e.g. "one [of them]".

Comment: But "any" does appear in indefinite pronoun in standard text.

Comment: The problem seems to be that there are (at least) two meanings of "any". One can usually be replaced with "a" or "an"; the other is a pronoun. But it doesn't follow that "a" or "an" is a pronoun.

Comment: @AndreasBlass It doesn't *necessarily* follow. See my answer below.

Comment: @Araucaria Is the following grammatical? "The OP is looking for a/n" The indefinite article is not the same word as "one".

Comment: @Mari-LouA It wasn't me who said it was! My comment was a tongue in cheek response to Reg. [However!! There are many words that can be seen to inflect not for case, but for whether they have a complement or not. For example take the word *no/ none* or the word *our/ours*. So there is a case to answer that *a* is the  unstrassesd intransitive form of the word *one*. The word *my/mine* used to work like *a/an* does today but changed to inflecting according to whether there was a following noun. Also consider the following alternations and then fill in the missing word: ...

Comment: @Mari-LouA *He's got some new toys. He's got some. / Give me that toy. Give me that. Give me a toy / Give me ___* ]. That's not my opinion, but it is an argument worth considering, if ever there was an. :-) (No, that's not a typo there!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Traditionally, *a* is regarded as a determinative.  Traditionally, *any* is considered a determinative when used with a following noun and either a determinative or a pronoun when used on its own, depending on which grammar one subscribes to. However, it can be argued that such analyses have got it wrong. (That isn't my own view)

Strange though it may seem, there are very good reasons for arguing that words like *a* and *the* are the same type of word as *you* or *we*. However, it is important to understand that these are not traditional analyses.

---

**Full answer**

This looks like a simple cut and dried question. It might even seem trivially simple. However, far from it, it is a rivetingly interesting problem, and one that has been much discussed in the literature.

**Preamble**

Before we can get going we need to have a look at the anatomy of noun phrases. Most grammars of English recognise that noun phrases are comprised of two smaller chunks or phrases. Consider the following noun phrase:

- the slimy dinosaur

Here we can divide the phrase into the chunk *the* and then the second part, *slimy dinosaur*. This reflects the fact that *slimy dinosaur* seems to have a coherence that *the slimy* doesn't.

Just as we see special names for the jobs done within a clause, for example *Subject* or *Object*, the jobs that different parts of a noun phrase carry out can also can be given similar titles. Words or phrases that appear as the first chunk, such as the word *the* in the example above, do the job of *Determiner*. The chunks that come after them, that contain the main noun, can be referred to as *Heads*.

Now, in many grammars, in the same way that Subjects are very frequently nouns or noun phrases, Determiners are frequently determinatives. Determinatives are commonly thought to be words such as *the, some, any* and so forth. However, just in the same way that Subjects are not always noun phrases, but may be clauses, adjective phrases and so forth, Determiners are not always determinatives. Sometimes, the Determiner job may be done by another phrase such as a noun phrase. Consider

- Bob's slimy dinosaur
- That man's slimy dinosaur

In the examples above, the Determiners are the noun phrases *Bob's* and *That man's* respectively. They aren't determinatives. Ok, so back to the Original Poster's question.

**Modern  and traditional grammars: *any***

Let's start with the word *any*. Typically, this word occurs on the left edge of noun phrases:

1. I couldn't find any new books.
2. I couldn't find any.

In most twentieth century grammars, the word *any* would  have been regarded as a determinative in (1) where it occurs to the left of the chunk *new books*. However, it would have been regarded as a pronoun in (2) where there is no following word or phrase.

Now, this seems a bit odd, because the word *any* seems to mean exactly the same thing in both examples. Notice that the verb *know* is still regarded as a verb in the following examples:

- I know that Bob left.
- I know.

In most twenty-first century grammars, the word *any* is treated as a determinative in both (1) and (2) above. We might want to construe those sentences like this:

- I could find [any new books]
- I couldn't find [any <s>new books</s>]

Just as we could construe the *know* examples like this:

- I [know that Bob left]
- I [know <s>that Bob left</s>]

The fact that there are no following words does not mean that the preceding word has a different part of speech in each case.

**Modern and traditional grammars *a(n)***

In most modern and traditional grammars, the words *a* and *the* are termed *articles*. These are usually considered a subcategory of the determinatives. Along with the word *every*, these determinatives cannot appear without a following phrase:

- Can I have a book?
- *Can I have a? (ungrammatical)
- Can I have the book?
- *Can I have the? (ungrammatical)

Compare those with:

- Can I have any custard?
- Can I have any?
- Can I have that book?
- Can I have that?

Here we see that the determinatives *any* and *that* can occur with or without a following word or phrase.

**Now for the interesting bit**

OK, so far so good. However, we touched upon a problem just now that hasn't been properly addressed. We looked at the verb *know* and saw that it could take a clause or occur without one. Of course, it can occur with a following noun phrase as well. This throws up some problems with the accounts given above.

In any description of a language it is useful to differentiate the jobs done within a clause or phrase, for example Subject or Determiner, with the type of word or phrase carrying out that job, for example a noun, adjective, verb (or noun phrase, adjective phrase or verb phrase).

Writers like Abney (1987), Hudson (2000) and Spinillo (2004) have argued that many of the words that are taken to be determintives are actually different types of word that happen to appear in Determiner function. So, for example, Spinillo argues that *many* is an adjective, not a deteminative. There are several reasons why this is most likely the case. Determinatives cannot occur as ascriptive Predicative Complements, where as adjectives can:

- Our objections were numerous.
- Our objections were many.
- *Our objections were some. (ungrammatical)
- *Our objections were any. (ungrammatical)

Determinatives cannot iterate, whilst adjectives can:

- blue, blue eyes
- many, many eyes
- *the, the eyes (ungrammatical)
- *some, some eyes (ungrammatical)

Certain types of adjectives can occur before entire noun phrases. Typical 'determinatives' cannot:

- bigger a problem
- many a problem
- *this a problem (ungrammatical)
- *some a problem (ungrammatical)

Generally, adjectives are likely to be gradeable, traditional typical determinatives are not:

- good people / better people / best people
- many people / more people / most people
- some people / *somer people /*somest people (non-existent)

Lastly (but only because of time constraints), adjectives are regularly modifiable by degree adverbs such as *so* and *how* whereas proptotypical determinatives aren't:

- so big
- how big?
- so many
- how many?
- *so some (ungrammatical)
- *how some? (ungrammatical)

Most, but not all, of the above is from Spinillo (see references). In this kind of way many determinatives can be dispatched to either the adjective or noun categories, to leave a much small number of central items. These words are nearly all monosyllabic. They don't iterate, aren't easily modifiable by adjectives, cannot occur with other similar words, don't occur as ascriptive predicative complements, have little or no internal morphology, are high frequency, occur in initial position in noun phrases.

These qualities are all also ones observed in the pronoun category. As we have already seen, most so-called determinatives can occur without a following noun just like pronouns - which is the main reason that they have been categorised as pronouns when doing so. The argument that determinatives and pronouns are actually the same type of word would be stronger if prototypical pronouns could also function in the same way as determinatives.

Now consider the following:

- We band of brothers
- You bastards
- Them idiots (in several non-standard dialects)

Here we see words that are commonly held to be pronouns occurring in Determiner function. We can compare these with traditional determinatives:

- We band of brothers will never leave
- We will never leave
- This spot will never disappear.
- This will never disappear.
- You bastards always annoy me.
- You always annoy me.
- Some members will come
- Some will come

Here we see 'pronouns' behaving like prototypical 'determinatives' and 'determinatives' behaving like prototypical 'pronouns'.

**The final move**

Above we saw that we always count verbs as verbs regardless of whether they occur before clauses or noun phrases. If we treat determinatives/pronouns in the same way, then we  have some that occur with an optional following noun phrase (*this, some, we* etc), some which cannot occur with a following noun phrase (*I*, *they* etc) and then finally some that must occur with a following noun phrase (*every, the, a*). This would mirror the behaviour of other types of word, such as verbs, which can be optionally transitive, always transitive or always intransitive.

This type of analysis, of course, raises many other questions. For example, are these words best analysed as all determinatives' or all 'pronouns' - and if they are pronouns, are they a subcategory of noun? It also calls into question whether it is the determinative or the common noun which is the head of the phrases that we traditionally regard as noun phrases.

Writers like Dick Hudson argue that these words, including the articles, are all pronouns - in which case, as the Original Poster intuitively guesses, *a* is—just like the word *any*—a pronoun!

<sup>[Note that Hudson does explicitly state that the word *a* is a pronoun, even though it cannot occur on its own]</sup>

---

References:

This slovenly explanation here is wanting on many fronts, largely because of time and space and the author's own failings and general laziness. However, here are some of the most important references if the reader wishes to do any further reading:

- Ben Jonson 1640 *The English grammar* [The Scholar Press 1972] <sup>in which he discusses articles as a subctegory of pronoun</sup>
- Steven P Abney 1987 *The noun phrase in its sentential aspect* MIT Press
- Dick (Richard) Hudson 1997 Syntax without functional categories *UCL working papers in linguistics*  **9** pp. 253-279.
- Mariangela Spinillo 2004 *Reconceptualising the English Determiner Class*. PhD thesis, University College London.

Comment: You've said at the top that  a non-traditional view is that a/an/the are pronouns. But the rest of your long answer only gives a very small proportion of examples about a/an/the but without explaining how they are pronominal (only that they are adjectival but have a few properties different from most other adjectives. So I fear this is misleading to the OP. _How_ non-traditional is this 'articles are pronouns' view? Can you add evidence as to the pronominal character of articles?

Comment: @Mitch Well, it's basically: They're monosyllabic. They don't iterate, aren't easily modifiable by adjectives, cannot occur with other similar words, don't occur as predicative complements, have little or no internal morphology, are high frequency, occur in initial position in noun phrases.

Comment: Araucaria, those all seem like coincidental characteristics not defining characteristics. This is all missing a definition of these grammar words. A [pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronoun) is "a word that substitutes for a noun or noun phrase". An [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_(grammar)) is "a word ... used  to specify grammatical definiteness of an [attached] noun"....

Comment: ... These definitions are very far apart. They certainly both _can_ apply to the word 'any' (not at the same time), and I imagine a very very weak argument for 'the' having some referencing (weakened over time). But 'a/an' themselves don't  have any _definitional_ 'pro-form' features. To say that 'a/an' is a pronoun for the reasons you cited is like calling a penguin a kind of panda because they're both black and white and cute. That's not how labels work.

Comment: @Mitch The argument  is that that line has been drawn in the wrong place. The arguement is that that type of definition is based on valency as well as mistaking grammatical relations with parts of speech (see the Hudson attached). They would argue that such definitions are useless for linguistic description or analysis. That's the line along which the disagreement is drawn.

Comment: @Mitch They are arguing that calling animals the same or different things on the basis of their colour (as opposed to more important, relevant qualities) is exactly analogous to what the traditional accounts do! [I'm just explaining to you what they say]

Comment: OK.  Your explanation of what they are doing makes sense to me. _What_ they are doing makes no sense to me for many reasons. They may have some deep theoretical understanding that I just cannot grasp, but I think the traditional definitions of pronoun and article help a language learner and those superficial features like 'monosyllabic' and 'high frequency' that they share are immaterial to how to 'a/an' and their meaning.

Comment: @Araucaria - You make a good point, **if** you are willing to make *pronouns* a subset of *determinatives*, instead of *articles* a subset of *pronouns*.  All pronouns 'determine', but all pronouns are also indexical, and 'the' is the only indexical article.  If history was different, we could use the articles as pronouns, but instead we change 'a[n]' to 'one' (="one of the things"), and we change 'the' to 'it' (="the thing").

Answer (score 5):

**Both** "any" and "a" are **determiners** - words which are used at the beginning of a noun group to indicate, for example, which thing you are referring to or whether you are referring to one thing or several.

But we cannot say that "**any**" is both an article and a pronoun. "Any" can be used in a few ways: as a **determiner** (e.g. *Is there any book on the table?*), as a **pronoun** (e.g. *I looked around for toilet paper, but there wasn’t any*), and as an **adverb** (e.g. *Are you feeling any better?*). So, "any" is never an article (only *a/an* and *the* are articles).

Note that "an answer" and "any answer" are not the same thing. Compare:

> I need **an** answer. (I need *one* answer)
>
> I need **any** answer. (I need *an/one* answer and it doesn't matter what it will be like)

Another example:

> I would like to read **an** *(one/some)* adventure book. - Which one? - **Any** book will do ("any" shows that I don't care which, it just must be an adventure book).

Comment: @MathWizard - Because the Pists determined that we do.

Comment: More precisely, I believe that article should be part of indefinite pronoun.

Comment: Aargh, that horrible practice of ascribing a part of speech according to a words complementaion. All a bit nineteenth-century .. ;-) Twenty-first century grammars would tend to regard *any* as a determinative in each case there. The difference is between their grammatical relations.

Comment: To clarify: in your example "... there wasn't any", "any" is not a pronoun but a determinative. Functionally, it's still a determiner -- a 'fused determiner-head' to be precise.

Comment: But "any" does appear in indefinite pronoun in standard text.

Comment: @BillJ How is "any" not a pronoun in "I need a volunteer. I'll take any." "Any" being the pronoun/anaphor and "volunteer" being the antecedent? I understand it's also a determiner, in that you'll take "any", as opposed to "all", or "some", but I don't see how it isn't still a pronoun.

Comment: @Zebrafish Well, 21st century grammarians like Huddleston & Pullum, or Bas Aarts, would say that you are confusing the grammatical relations with the parts of speech there. They would say that the wod *any* is the Head of the noun phrase in *I'll take [any]*, but the Determiner in *I'll take [any volunteer]*. However, the fact that it has different grammatical relations in each case doesn't mean it is a different part of speech (it is a determinative in both). This is  ...

Comment: @Zebrafish ... the same as *water* being a noun in *Water is good for you* and in *I like water*, where it is the Subject in the first example and the Object in the second. A change in the grammatical relations does not mean a change of the part of speech. That's what they'd say. For H&P, a pronoun is a type of noun, whereas a determinative is not. Pronouns prototypically cannot occur with a following common noun, determinatives prototypically can. (That's what they'd say)

Comment: @Araucaria I think it's a good idea to mention that this "any" is a fused determiner-head. Thus, in "Ed has two kids but I don't have any", the single word "any" is both determiner and head of the NP. Hopefully, this would dispel any notion that it is a pronoun. Btw, I mentioned that term in my first comment, but the problem is that some of the contributors here wouldn't know a fused determiner-head from a hole in the ground!

Comment: @BillJ Yes, I agree which is why I stuck with Head (the most important bit of that). I think most people are happy to understand *any* as having an ellipted noun. Any chance of a reopen vote on this Q?

Comment: @Araucaria Done! Well, those who think it's a pronoun in "I don't have any" seem intransigent on this point. I understand why they are, since trad grammar calls it a pronoun, as do dictionaries such as the Oxford.

Comment: @BillJ Well, there's some who argue that all determinatives are actually pronouns  - or all pronouns are determinatives which amount to much the same thing. I'm not one of that crew, but the arguments are interesting. I've written a post below (which has almost as many downvotes as upvotes (no surprises there). I'm with H&P on this one :)

Comment: @Araucaria I like the answer very much. H&P say that "any" and "some" for example, express existential quantification and occur primarily in determiner function where they mark an NP as indefinite. Any word that marks an NP as definite or indefinite must be a determiner, I guess.

Comment: @BillJ To those who are being "intransigent" you would have to add the dictionaries:  OED, OLO, Cambridge, Collins, American Heritage, Merriam-Webster, Macmillan, Random House Unabridged, as they all list "any" as pronoun. Among the examples given are: "We don't have any left.", "don't give her any.", "someone asked him for a match, but Joe didn't have any."  Your term shows about 200 results in a Google search, the first instance being in 1999 by Huddleston & Pullum. So as I see it this categorisation is a rather new one, all the dictionaries have remained "intransigent" to this new wisdom.

Comment: @Araucaria "there's some who argue that all determinatives are actually pronouns - or all pronouns are determinatives which amount to much the same thing" What? If they're the same thing, then you'd have to say that all cats being mammals means all mammals are cats???

Comment: @curiousdannii No, in the cats and mammals one is a subset of the other, there's still two  categories. Here the claim both ways is that there is only one category. One lot say that there is just a category  *pronoun* and no category *determiner* the other lot say there's just the category *determiner* and there's no such category as *pronoun*. So both sets of people agree on there being one homogenous category, but they disagree about its name.

Comment: @Araucaria And both are the minority position. Most linguists would say that determinative is a category including "definite and indefinite articles (like the English the and a or an), demonstratives (this and that), possessive determiners (my and their), quantifiers (many, few and several), numerals, distributive determiners (each, any), and interrogative determiners (which)." (Wikipedia)

Comment: @curiousdanni Sorry, are you trying to make some kind of point?

Comment: @Zebrafish Yes, exactly. It's very difficult to overhaul entire dictionaries (in the OED, some entries haven't been updated for decades); that's why they stick to certain antiquated categorizations despite their having been obsoleted by modern grammars. At least they're consistent; wrong, but consistent. You've proved nothing by quoting all those dictionaries, by the way, and as linguists (people who study grammar) here will tell you, they're by no means authoritative on this issue.

Comment: @user2684291 The OED is a dictionary unlike most dictionaries I spoke of, namely a historical dictionary. It's had only one new edition, the last one being in 1989. American Heritage's last edition was in 2011, Cambridge's last in 2013, and Collins' in 2014. The Wikipedia English Grammar article says: "Many words that serve as determiners can also be used as pronouns (this, that, many, etc.)". I feel that you'll repeat not to trust dictionaries and even not trust Wikipedia. It seems to me that if grammarians are settled on this issue then one wouldn't find such information in abundance.

Answer (score -1):

There are two philosophical strategies in linguistics that I think lead to inaccuracies of labeling:

- a word has a single meaning, and, relatedly,
- a word to belongs to exactly a single part of speech category.

For example, 'this' can act sometimes like an adjective and sometimes like a pronoun (sometimes *at* the same time).

The question seems to come with an assumption that determiners are pronouns, and since 'a' and 'any' are determiners, they must them logically be pronouns. Logic works well with correct assumptions. It turns out that only *some* determiners are pronouns (or rather pronominal).

The primary question here is about 'any' and 'a'. The given examples show that 'any' can act both like an adjective and like a pronoun.

'Any' and 'a' are similar (and have similar etymologies), but that does not make them the same. I can think of no instance where 'a' acts pronominally. All sentences, trying to use 'a' as a stand alone *or* to refer to something previously mentioned, like:

> *I don't have a

(in analogy to 'I don't have any') not only are nonsensical, they are ungrammatical.

So, whatever label you want to apply to it, 'a' is not a pronoun.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84204/discussion-on-answer-by-mitch-are-articles-pronouns).

Comment: I think this is exactly a question of labeling, so I’m not satisfied with the last sentence of this answer. You seem to be assuming a definition of “pronoun” that has not been demonstrated here to be a useful/necessary category for linguistic analysis.

Comment: Any time a determiner occurs without a noun, it is a mistake to look for a noun hidden (fused) in the determiner.  It is better to consider that a pronoun has been elided (cf. "I like cats.  Do you have any [of them]?").